# Not able to insert data in to sqlite database on iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am trying to create(successful), insert(problem here) and select(just to check i i am going right) records into data base.

My whole code is as:

```
-(NSInteger) InsertDataInDatabae {

    char *sqlStatement;
    sqlite3 *pDb;
    char *errorMsg;
    int returnCode;
    char *databaseName;
    databaseName="WaitListAll.db";
    returnCode = sqlite3_open(databaseName, &pDb);

    if(returnCode!=SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Error in opening Database");
        return -1;
    }
    sqlStatement="drop table if exists waitlistallTable";
    returnCode = sqlite3_exec(pDb, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &errorMsg);

    if(returnCode!=SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Table could not be droped");
        return -1;
    }

    sqlStatement="create table waitlistallTable(source varchar(10),waitlistid varchar(10),""restaurantid varchar(10),consumerid varchar(10), timeadded varchar(10))";

    returnCode=sqlite3_exec(pDb, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &errorMsg);
    if(returnCode!=SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Table could not be Created Error:%@",errorMsg);//**getting error here as:unrecognized token ""**
        return -1;
    }

    NSInteger  i;
    for(i=0;i<[waitListAllRecordsArray count];i++) {
        NSDictionary *objDict=[waitListAllRecordsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *src,*wid,*rid,*cid,*tadded;
        src=[objDict objectForKey:@"SOURCE"];
        wid=[objDict objectForKey:@"WAITLISTID"];
        rid=[objDict objectForKey:@"RESTAURANTID"];
        cid=[objDict objectForKey:@"CONSUMERID"];
        tadded=[objDict objectForKey:@"TIMEADDED"];
        printf("\n %s %s %s  %s %s",src,wid,rid,cid);
        sqlStatement = sqlite3_mprintf("insert into waitlistallTable values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",src,wid,rid,cid,tadded);

        returnCode=sqlite3_exec(pDb, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &errorMsg);

        if(returnCode!=SQLITE_OK) {
            printf("Error in inserting record :%s",errorMsg);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    sqlStatement=sqlite3_mprintf("selet * from waitlistallTable");
    returnCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(pDb, sqlStatement, strlen(sqlStatement), &statement,NULL);
    if(returnCode!=SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Record could  not be Inserted  Error:%@",errorMsg);
        return -1;
    }

    returnCode=sqlite3_step(statement);
    while(returnCode==SQLITE_ROW) {
        char *src,*wid,*rid,*cid,*tadded;
        src=sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        wid=sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        rid=sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
        cid=sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
        tadded=sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4);
        NSLog(@"%@\t %@\t %@ \t%@ %@",src,wid,rid, cid,tadded);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(&pDb);

    //  sqlite3_free(sqlStatement);
    //NSLog(@"%@\t %@\t %@ \t%@ %@",src,wid,rid, cid,tadded);       //NSLog(@"*******object for dictionary is **************%@",[objDict objectForKey:@"SOURCE"]);
}
```

Any suggestion would be very helpful.
thanks

Comment: you've set all column types to `varchar(10)`. Could that be the problem on inserting `NSString *src,*wid,*rid,*cid,*tadded;` values if they exceeds 10 bytes?

Comment: @denolk thanks!let me check for this!

Comment: An error `selet * from waitlistallTable` or a typo in the question here?

Comment: @tim hanks for looking at my problem actually control was not going upto select statemant it was exist from insert error,how ever have been fixed now!see my comment in SAMfisher answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to insert NSString object with %s formatter,
try out:

```
sqlStatement=sqlite3_mprintf("insert into waitlistallTable values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",[src UTF8String],[wid UTF8String],[rid UTF8String],[cid UTF8String],[tadded UTF8String]);
```

hope it'll help..!

Comment: thanks man! i have to change from your to sqlStatement=sqlite3_mprintf("insert into waitlistallTable values('%q', '%q', '%q', '%q', '%q')",[src UTF8String],[wid UTF8String],[rid UTF8String],[cid UTF8String],[tadded UTF8String]);   just added '%q' and working fine

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO history (prescriptionname,prescriptiondate,doctorname,personname,profileid) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)

Insert the values using above format

Comment: ram! can you please elaborate more so that your answer could be useful!tanks